# Update max value to -1 in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array:

```
L = array([[ 4,  5,  3, 10,  1],
           [10,  1, 10, 10,  5],
           [ 1,  6,  3,  2,  7],
           [ 5,  1,  1,  5,  1],
           [ 8,  8,  8, 10,  5]])
```

I need to change maximum value to -1. Result array will be like below:

```
R = array([[ 4,  5,  3, -1,  1],
           [-1,  1, -1, -1,  5],
           [ 1,  6,  3,  2,  7],
           [ 5,  1,  1,  5,  1],
           [ 8,  8,  8, -1,  5]])
```

My array L will be a random 5*5 size array.. How can i do this?

Comment: You need to provide the effort you've made so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L = np.array([[ 4,  5,  3, 10,  1],
...               [10,  1, 10, 10,  5],
...               [ 1,  6,  3,  2,  7],
...               [ 5,  1,  1,  5,  1],
...               [ 8,  8,  8, 10,  5]])
>>> R = L.copy()
>>> R[R==R.max()]=-1
>>> R
array([[ 4,  5,  3, -1,  1],
       [-1,  1, -1, -1,  5],
       [ 1,  6,  3,  2,  7],
       [ 5,  1,  1,  5,  1],
       [ 8,  8,  8, -1,  5]])
```

Comment: I can't test it right now but I think `np.where` is not completely needed. If I'm not wrong `R[R == R.max()] = -1` should do the job as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure Python (without Numpy) I would do it like this

```
# 1) the list as supplied
L = [[ 4,  5,  3, 10,  1],
     [10,  1, 10, 10,  5],
     [ 1,  6,  3,  2,  7],
     [ 5,  1,  1,  5,  1],
     [ 8,  8,  8, 10,  5]]

# 2) helper function
def check(item, row, L):
    maximum = max([x for y in L for x in y])
    return -1 if item is maximum else item

# 3) apply the check to all elements of L, save as R
R = [[check(item,row,L) for item in row] for row in L]
```

The result

```
>>> R

[[ 4,  5,  3, -1,  1],
 [-1,  1, -1, -1,  5],
 [ 1,  6,  3,  2, -1],
 [-1,  1,  1, -1,  1],
 [ 8,  8,  8, -1,  5]]
```

Comment: This only considers the `max` in a per row basis.

Comment: Thanks @iluengo I've repaired the max-determination to be `max` of the whole collection instead of each row

Comment: Now it works :D However, you can calculate the maximum just once, instead of once per row. (Just suggestions to improve it, hope you dont hate me too much).